# What kind of wall port is this?

Tags: connector

I moved into a new apartment, which provides internet for me, and I assume the port in the image was an Ethernet port, but on closer inspection, it is not. What is it, and can it be used to connect my router?

[image]

P.S. While I know this may not be the place to ask, I didn't see any other stack exchange devoted even remotely to hardware, and so asked here.

Comment: "it is not" Why do you say that?

Comment: No, don't close

Comment: Open it up, look how many wires are connected to it? The country you are in would also be a valuable piece of information.

Comment: Looks like an ethernet jack IBDN Integrated Building Distribution Network that is extremely dirty

Comment: I see 8 pins in what looks like an RJ-45. Looks like Ethernet, smells like Ethernet ...

Comment: Intrinsic Buildup of Dust Node

Comment: "on closer inspection, it is not."  What convinced you?

Comment: Get a vacuum cleaner and clean a little socket if you'd like to have a good contacts, it looks really dirty to me. As about your question, such RJ-45 sockets can be used for anything(mostly ethernet) and if it would be me, I would ask maintenance guys  or manager about this "How to"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an RJ45 (8pin connector, but I can barely tell from the photo).

What really makes the difference is what it is connected to, generally ethernet is used with RJ45's but who really knows.

RJ11 or RJ25 (2 lines and 3 lines is usually phone)

Answer (score 0):

**IBDN - Integrated Building Distribution Network.**

This is the use of (typically) Cat 5/RJ45 network cables for building management services.

While they don't differ from a tradition network in terms fo the cabling used, the types of heads on the cables etc - often, when true IBDN is used - the patching at the other end of the cables behind these ports goes into a completely separate patch panel/switch speifically segregated to keep building monitoring away from other services which use networking technologies.  Think of it as a separate building management network.

These can also be used for Internet etc as they take standard 8-pin RJ45 connectors - the only difference between use for the internet and use for Building Management systems is what the other end of the cable is plugged into!

If your landlord is using these for providing network connectivity - odds are the building used to be used for a business.  If this has always been a residential building - your landlord probably got them cheap (and a very long time ago judging by the dicoloration and dust build up!)

Yes they can be used to connect to your router - providing you can find the other end of the cable behind that face plate and its patched somewhere suitably.

Comment: Do make sure you know what the other end is connected to though.  If it's a phone line, it _will_ fry most routers the first time it tries to ring.